# How to fit multiple spectra to a spectrum by extracting the coefficients from a least-squares linear fit?

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

I want to fit two different spectra to my original spectrum. The two different spectra have x and y values of:

x_1 = 1700.42
1700.9
1701.38
1701.86
1702.34
1702.83
1703.31
1703.79
1704.27
1704.75
1705.24
1705.72
1706.2
1706.68
1707.17
1707.65
1708.13
1708.61
1709.09
1709.58
1710.06
1710.54
1711.02
1711.5
1711.99
1712.47
1712.95
1713.43
1713.91
1714.4
1714.88
1715.36
1715.84
1716.33
1716.81
1717.29
1717.77
1718.25
1718.74
1719.22
1719.7
1720.18
1720.66
1721.15
1721.63
1722.11
1722.59
1723.08
1723.56
1724.04
1724.52
1725
1725.49
1725.97
1726.45
1726.93
1727.41
1727.9
1728.38
1728.86
1729.34
1729.82
1730.31
1730.79
1731.27
1731.75
1732.24
1732.72
1733.2
1733.68
1734.16
1734.65
1735.13
1735.61
1736.09
1736.57
1737.06
1737.54
1738.02
1738.5
1738.98
1739.47
1739.95
1740.43
1740.91
1741.4
1741.88
1742.36
1742.84
1743.32
1743.81
1744.29
1744.77
1745.25
1745.73
1746.22
1746.7
1747.18
1747.66
1748.14
1748.63
1749.11
1749.59
1750.07
1750.56

y_1 = 0.00285
0.00289
0.00290
0.00292
0.00297
0.00304
0.00310
0.00314
0.00319
0.00323
0.00327
0.00333
0.00340
0.00344
0.00347
0.00352
0.00358
0.00364
0.00369
0.00374
0.00382
0.00388
0.00392
0.00397
0.00403
0.00408
0.00414
0.00420
0.00428
0.00436
0.00444
0.00451
0.00456
0.00461
0.00468
0.00474
0.00480
0.00486
0.00493
0.00501
0.00509
0.00517
0.00524
0.00530
0.00535
0.00543
0.00551
0.00558
0.00564
0.00571
0.00578
0.00587
0.00594
0.00599
0.00607
0.00615
0.00623
0.00631
0.00636
0.00645
0.00657
0.00666
0.00673
0.00682
0.00688
0.00695
0.00704
0.00713
0.00722
0.00732
0.00741
0.00750
0.00758
0.00768
0.00777
0.00783
0.00788
0.00792
0.00795
0.00799
0.00803
0.00806
0.00807
0.00804
0.00800
0.00795
0.00787
0.00779
0.00767
0.00753
0.00737
0.00719
0.00699
0.00677
0.00652
0.00626
0.00599
0.00572
0.00546
0.00519
0.00492
0.00465
0.00437
0.00413
0.00391

and x_2 = 1700.42 1700.9 1701.38 1701.86 1702.34 1702.83 1703.31 1703.79 1704.27 1704.75 1705.24 1705.72 1706.2 1706.68 1707.17 1707.65 1708.13 1708.61 1709.09 1709.58 1710.06 1710.54 1711.02 1711.5 1711.99 1712.47 1712.95 1713.43 1713.91 1714.4 1714.88 1715.36 1715.84 1716.33 1716.81 1717.29 1717.77 1718.25 1718.74 1719.22 1719.7 1720.18 1720.66 1721.15 1721.63 1722.11 1722.59 1723.08 1723.56 1724.04 1724.52 1725 1725.49 1725.97 1726.45 1726.93 1727.41 1727.9 1728.38 1728.86 1729.34 1729.82 1730.31 1730.79 1731.27 1731.75 1732.24 1732.72 1733.2 1733.68 1734.16 1734.65 1735.13 1735.61 1736.09 1736.57 1737.06 1737.54 1738.02 1738.5 1738.98 1739.47 1739.95 1740.43 1740.91 1741.4 1741.88 1742.36 1742.84 1743.32 1743.81 1744.29 1744.77 1745.25 1745.73 1746.22 1746.7 1747.18 1747.66 1748.14 1748.63 1749.11 1749.59 1750.07 1750.56

y_2 = 0.00182478
0.00198449
0.0021542
0.00230491
0.00248363
0.00269334
0.00289705
0.00308676
0.00330747
0.00358919
0.0038779
0.00415561
0.00444332
0.00474103
0.00507474
0.00542346
0.00576517
0.00613688
0.00651859
0.0068873
0.00727502
0.00767773
0.00808544
0.00851815
0.00894486
0.00935658
0.00979429
0.010245
0.0106727
0.0110844
0.0115191
0.0119878
0.0124556
0.0128823
0.013274
0.0137237
0.0142374
0.0147181
0.0151798
0.0156495
0.0160963
0.016534
0.0169657
0.0173574
0.0177211
0.0180818
0.0184125
0.0187012
0.0189339
0.0191077
0.0192454
0.0193291
0.0193638
0.0193495
0.0192672
0.0191119
0.0188696
0.0185614
0.0181941
0.0176948
0.0170465
0.0162762
0.0153449
0.0142406
0.0129863
0.0115801
0.0100468
0.00844248
0.00692419
0.0055719
0.00435861
0.00340132
0.00270704
0.00213775
0.00168046
0.00134117
0.00109188
9.16595E-4
7.80307E-4
6.65019E-4
5.62731E-4
4.75443E-4
4.42155E-4
4.49867E-4
4.29579E-4
3.9929E-4
3.83002E-4
3.51714E-4
3.38426E-4
3.40138E-4
3.2985E-4
3.27562E-4
3.24274E-4
3.06986E-4
2.92698E-4
3.0041E-4
3.12121E-4
2.84833E-4
2.47545E-4
2.41257E-4
2.34969E-4
2.27681E-4
2.47393E-4
2.60105E-4
2.25817E-4

My original data:

x_orig = 1700.42
1700.9
1701.38
1701.86
1702.34
1702.83
1703.31
1703.79
1704.27
1704.75
1705.24
1705.72
1706.2
1706.68
1707.17
1707.65
1708.13
1708.61
1709.09
1709.58
1710.06
1710.54
1711.02
1711.5
1711.99
1712.47
1712.95
1713.43
1713.91
1714.4
1714.88
1715.36
1715.84
1716.33
1716.81
1717.29
1717.77
1718.25
1718.74
1719.22
1719.7
1720.18
1720.66
1721.15
1721.63
1722.11
1722.59
1723.08
1723.56
1724.04
1724.52
1725
1725.49
1725.97
1726.45
1726.93
1727.41
1727.9
1728.38
1728.86
1729.34
1729.82
1730.31
1730.79
1731.27
1731.75
1732.24
1732.72
1733.2
1733.68
1734.16
1734.65
1735.13
1735.61
1736.09
1736.57
1737.06
1737.54
1738.02
1738.5
1738.98
1739.47
1739.95
1740.43
1740.91
1741.4
1741.88
1742.36
1742.84
1743.32
1743.81
1744.29
1744.77
1745.25
1745.73
1746.22
1746.7
1747.18
1747.66
1748.14
1748.63
1749.11
1749.59
1750.07
1750.56

y_orig = 0.011507
0.0121121
0.0127542
0.0132673
0.0137554
0.0143684
0.0148995
0.0154036
0.0159997
0.0165907
0.0172408
0.0178499
0.018388
0.019089
0.0197701
0.0203572
0.0210393
0.0216564
0.0222324
0.0228305
0.0233166
0.0238667
0.0244387
0.0248918
0.0254159
0.025865
0.026158
0.0265131
0.0267652
0.0269333
0.0271824
0.0273214
0.0274515
0.0274626
0.0271257
0.0269957
0.0270148
0.0267899
0.026651
0.026427
0.0260381
0.0257212
0.0252253
0.0247254
0.0243314
0.0237925
0.0233076
0.0227997
0.0221607
0.0216288
0.0210079
0.020299
0.019702
0.0189881
0.0182382
0.0175053
0.0165944
0.0157524
0.0149355
0.0139746
0.0131167
0.0122307
0.0112948
0.0105009
0.00964397
0.00886105
0.00821613
0.0074542
0.00685928
0.00640136
0.00589444
0.00568351
0.00555559
0.00529467
0.00514074
0.00495682
0.0047789
0.00469697
0.00453005
0.00441613
0.0042912
0.00408328
0.00409536
0.00412444
0.00400951
0.00397959
0.00389367
0.00375074
0.00372082
0.0036819
0.00365497
0.00363905
0.00353413
0.00348721
0.00346528
0.00336936
0.00334044
0.00331251
0.00322459
0.00316767
0.00308874
0.00304882
0.0030859
0.00301798
0.00287005

How do I fit the two spectra to the original spectrum by extracting the coefficients from a least-squares linear fit? I use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit using gaussians, but now I need to just fit data.

Answer (score 1):

When I scatterplot the data, it looks like three separate, somewhat asymmetrical peaks - I would think this requires one peak fit for each set of data. Please see my image and code below.

[image]

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_1 = numpy.array([1700.42, 1700.9, 1701.38, 1701.86, 1702.34, 1702.83, 1703.31, 1703.79, 1704.27, 1704.75, 1705.24, 1705.72, 1706.2, 1706.68, 1707.17, 1707.65, 1708.13, 1708.61, 1709.09, 1709.58, 1710.06, 1710.54, 1711.02, 1711.5, 1711.99, 1712.47, 1712.95, 1713.43, 1713.91, 1714.4, 1714.88, 1715.36, 1715.84, 1716.33, 1716.81, 1717.29, 1717.77, 1718.25, 1718.74, 1719.22, 1719.7, 1720.18, 1720.66, 1721.15, 1721.63, 1722.11, 1722.59, 1723.08, 1723.56, 1724.04, 1724.52, 1725, 1725.49, 1725.97, 1726.45, 1726.93, 1727.41, 1727.9, 1728.38, 1728.86, 1729.34, 1729.82, 1730.31, 1730.79, 1731.27, 1731.75, 1732.24, 1732.72, 1733.2, 1733.68, 1734.16, 1734.65, 1735.13, 1735.61, 1736.09, 1736.57, 1737.06, 1737.54, 1738.02, 1738.5, 1738.98, 1739.47, 1739.95, 1740.43, 1740.91, 1741.4, 1741.88, 1742.36, 1742.84, 1743.32, 1743.81, 1744.29, 1744.77, 1745.25, 1745.73, 1746.22, 1746.7, 1747.18, 1747.66, 1748.14, 1748.63, 1749.11, 1749.59, 1750.07, 1750.56])
y_1 = numpy.array([0.00285, 0.00289, 0.00290, 0.00292, 0.00297, 0.00304, 0.00310, 0.00314, 0.00319, 0.00323, 0.00327, 0.00333, 0.00340, 0.00344, 0.00347, 0.00352, 0.00358, 0.00364, 0.00369, 0.00374, 0.00382, 0.00388, 0.00392, 0.00397, 0.00403, 0.00408, 0.00414, 0.00420, 0.00428, 0.00436, 0.00444, 0.00451, 0.00456, 0.00461, 0.00468, 0.00474, 0.00480, 0.00486, 0.00493, 0.00501, 0.00509, 0.00517, 0.00524, 0.00530, 0.00535, 0.00543, 0.00551, 0.00558, 0.00564, 0.00571, 0.00578, 0.00587, 0.00594, 0.00599, 0.00607, 0.00615, 0.00623, 0.00631, 0.00636, 0.00645, 0.00657, 0.00666, 0.00673, 0.00682, 0.00688, 0.00695, 0.00704, 0.00713, 0.00722, 0.00732, 0.00741, 0.00750, 0.00758, 0.00768, 0.00777, 0.00783, 0.00788, 0.00792, 0.00795, 0.00799, 0.00803, 0.00806, 0.00807, 0.00804, 0.00800, 0.00795, 0.00787, 0.00779, 0.00767, 0.00753, 0.00737, 0.00719, 0.00699, 0.00677, 0.00652, 0.00626, 0.00599, 0.00572, 0.00546, 0.00519, 0.00492, 0.00465, 0.00437, 0.00413, 0.00391])

x_2 = numpy.array([1700.42, 1700.9, 1701.38, 1701.86, 1702.34, 1702.83, 1703.31, 1703.79, 1704.27, 1704.75, 1705.24, 1705.72, 1706.2, 1706.68, 1707.17, 1707.65, 1708.13, 1708.61, 1709.09, 1709.58, 1710.06, 1710.54, 1711.02, 1711.5, 1711.99, 1712.47, 1712.95, 1713.43, 1713.91, 1714.4, 1714.88, 1715.36, 1715.84, 1716.33, 1716.81, 1717.29, 1717.77, 1718.25, 1718.74, 1719.22, 1719.7, 1720.18, 1720.66, 1721.15, 1721.63, 1722.11, 1722.59, 1723.08, 1723.56, 1724.04, 1724.52, 1725, 1725.49, 1725.97, 1726.45, 1726.93, 1727.41, 1727.9, 1728.38, 1728.86, 1729.34, 1729.82, 1730.31, 1730.79, 1731.27, 1731.75, 1732.24, 1732.72, 1733.2, 1733.68, 1734.16, 1734.65, 1735.13, 1735.61, 1736.09, 1736.57, 1737.06, 1737.54, 1738.02, 1738.5, 1738.98, 1739.47, 1739.95, 1740.43, 1740.91, 1741.4, 1741.88, 1742.36, 1742.84, 1743.32, 1743.81, 1744.29, 1744.77, 1745.25, 1745.73, 1746.22, 1746.7, 1747.18, 1747.66, 1748.14, 1748.63, 1749.11, 1749.59, 1750.07, 1750.56])
y_2 = numpy.array([0.00182478, 0.00198449, 0.0021542, 0.00230491, 0.00248363, 0.00269334, 0.00289705, 0.00308676, 0.00330747, 0.00358919, 0.0038779, 0.00415561, 0.00444332, 0.00474103, 0.00507474, 0.00542346, 0.00576517, 0.00613688, 0.00651859, 0.0068873, 0.00727502, 0.00767773, 0.00808544, 0.00851815, 0.00894486, 0.00935658, 0.00979429, 0.010245, 0.0106727, 0.0110844, 0.0115191, 0.0119878, 0.0124556, 0.0128823, 0.013274, 0.0137237, 0.0142374, 0.0147181, 0.0151798, 0.0156495, 0.0160963, 0.016534, 0.0169657, 0.0173574, 0.0177211, 0.0180818, 0.0184125, 0.0187012, 0.0189339, 0.0191077, 0.0192454, 0.0193291, 0.0193638, 0.0193495, 0.0192672, 0.0191119, 0.0188696, 0.0185614, 0.0181941, 0.0176948, 0.0170465, 0.0162762, 0.0153449, 0.0142406, 0.0129863, 0.0115801, 0.0100468, 0.00844248, 0.00692419, 0.0055719, 0.00435861, 0.00340132, 0.00270704, 0.00213775, 0.00168046, 0.00134117, 0.00109188, 9.16595E-4, 7.80307E-4, 6.65019E-4, 5.62731E-4, 4.75443E-4, 4.42155E-4, 4.49867E-4, 4.29579E-4, 3.9929E-4, 3.83002E-4, 3.51714E-4, 3.38426E-4, 3.40138E-4, 3.2985E-4, 3.27562E-4, 3.24274E-4, 3.06986E-4, 2.92698E-4, 3.0041E-4, 3.12121E-4, 2.84833E-4, 2.47545E-4, 2.41257E-4, 2.34969E-4, 2.27681E-4, 2.47393E-4, 2.60105E-4, 2.25817E-4])

x_orig = numpy.array([1700.42, 1700.9, 1701.38, 1701.86, 1702.34, 1702.83, 1703.31, 1703.79, 1704.27, 1704.75, 1705.24, 1705.72, 1706.2, 1706.68, 1707.17, 1707.65, 1708.13, 1708.61, 1709.09, 1709.58, 1710.06, 1710.54, 1711.02, 1711.5, 1711.99, 1712.47, 1712.95, 1713.43, 1713.91, 1714.4, 1714.88, 1715.36, 1715.84, 1716.33, 1716.81, 1717.29, 1717.77, 1718.25, 1718.74, 1719.22, 1719.7, 1720.18, 1720.66, 1721.15, 1721.63, 1722.11, 1722.59, 1723.08, 1723.56, 1724.04, 1724.52, 1725, 1725.49, 1725.97, 1726.45, 1726.93, 1727.41, 1727.9, 1728.38, 1728.86, 1729.34, 1729.82, 1730.31, 1730.79, 1731.27, 1731.75, 1732.24, 1732.72, 1733.2, 1733.68, 1734.16, 1734.65, 1735.13, 1735.61, 1736.09, 1736.57, 1737.06, 1737.54, 1738.02, 1738.5, 1738.98, 1739.47, 1739.95, 1740.43, 1740.91, 1741.4, 1741.88, 1742.36, 1742.84, 1743.32, 1743.81, 1744.29, 1744.77, 1745.25, 1745.73, 1746.22, 1746.7, 1747.18, 1747.66, 1748.14, 1748.63, 1749.11, 1749.59, 1750.07, 1750.56])
y_orig = numpy.array([0.011507, 0.0121121, 0.0127542, 0.0132673, 0.0137554, 0.0143684, 0.0148995, 0.0154036, 0.0159997, 0.0165907, 0.0172408, 0.0178499, 0.018388, 0.019089, 0.0197701, 0.0203572, 0.0210393, 0.0216564, 0.0222324, 0.0228305, 0.0233166, 0.0238667, 0.0244387, 0.0248918, 0.0254159, 0.025865, 0.026158, 0.0265131, 0.0267652, 0.0269333, 0.0271824, 0.0273214, 0.0274515, 0.0274626, 0.0271257, 0.0269957, 0.0270148, 0.0267899, 0.026651, 0.026427, 0.0260381, 0.0257212, 0.0252253, 0.0247254, 0.0243314, 0.0237925, 0.0233076, 0.0227997, 0.0221607, 0.0216288, 0.0210079, 0.020299, 0.019702, 0.0189881, 0.0182382, 0.0175053, 0.0165944, 0.0157524, 0.0149355, 0.0139746, 0.0131167, 0.0122307, 0.0112948, 0.0105009, 0.00964397, 0.00886105, 0.00821613, 0.0074542, 0.00685928, 0.00640136, 0.00589444, 0.00568351, 0.00555559, 0.00529467, 0.00514074, 0.00495682, 0.0047789, 0.00469697, 0.00453005, 0.00441613, 0.0042912, 0.00408328, 0.00409536, 0.00412444, 0.00400951, 0.00397959, 0.00389367, 0.00375074, 0.00372082, 0.0036819, 0.00365497, 0.00363905, 0.00353413, 0.00348721, 0.00346528, 0.00336936, 0.00334044, 0.00331251, 0.00322459, 0.00316767, 0.00308874, 0.00304882, 0.0030859, 0.00301798, 0.00287005])

plt.plot(x_1, y_1,  'o')
plt.plot(x_2, y_2,  'o')
plt.plot(x_orig, y_orig,  'o')

plt.xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
plt.ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

plt.show()
```

Comment: My apologies, I was not very clear and will edit this in the original post. I am looking to extract a set of coefficients (perform a least-squares linear fit) that I can multiply the two data with so that I can fit the two spectra to the original spectrum.

Comment: Well, there are 3 parameters of interest as I understand this: 1) Peak center, 2) peak width, and 3) peak amplitude. If you were to fit the same peak equation to each of the data sets, yielding three sets of fitted coefficients the appropriate scaling and shifting factors should be more apparent.